# Rally Web Services API: How do I get the URL link of the user story? (getDetailUrl() method)

Tags: web-services, rally

Please be patient and Do Not flag this as duplicate: [Using the Rally REST API, how can I get the non-API (website) URL for a user story?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538441/using-the-rally-rest-api-how-can-i-get-the-non-api-website-url-for-a-user-sto)

I want to be able to generate a link for the user story.
Something like this: https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/-/detail/userstory/*********
As opposed to this: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement/88502329352

The link will be integrated into another application for the managers to see the user story.
I did read about the getDetailUrl() method, but in my case I am creating the user stories by parsing email and linking that to a notification service in Slack.
I am aware of the formattedID and (_ref), but I would have to query for it again, and I am creating batches of userstories through a loop. I need the actual web site link to the user story.

Here is my sample code:

```
public void CreateUserStory(string workspace, string project, string userstoryName){

//authenticate with Rally
this.EnsureRallyIsAuthenticated();

//DynamicJsonObject for HierarchicalRequirement
DynamicJsonObject toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
toCreate[RallyConstant.WorkSpace] = workspace;
toCreate[RallyConstant.Project] = project;
toCreate[RallyConstant.Name] = userstoryName;

 try
 {
    //Create the User Story Here
    CreateResult createUserStory = _api.Create(RallyConstant.HierarchicalRequirement, toCreate);
    Console.WriteLine("Created Userstory: " + "URL LINK GOES HERE");
 }
 catch (WebException e)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't have a method in the .NET toolkit for doing this, but it's easy to create.

The format is this:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/detail/<type>/<objectid>
```

Just fill in the type (hierarchicalrequirement turns into userstory, but all the others are the same as the wsapi type) and the objectid from the object you just created.

```
var parameters = new NameValueCollection();
parameters["fetch"] = "FormattedID";
var toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
var createResult = restApi.create("hierarchicalrequirement", toCreate, parameters); 
var type = Ref.getTypeFromRef(createResult.Reference);
var objectID = Ref.getOidFromRef(createResult.Reference);
var formattedID = createResult.Object["FormattedID"];
```

And you can specify fetch fields to be returned on the created object so you don't have to re-query for it.

Comment: Kyle: I am confused about the objectID and Type.
How would I access these fields after I create the user story.
I have a dynamicJSONObject, but those fields are not visible.
Can you provide a code sample. Thanks

Comment: i just updated the answer to include some more code to pull those values out of the response...

Comment: Is there a way to get the formattedID similar to the above code. (US111)

Comment: sure, you don't need it for the url, but it should just be createResult.Object["FormattedID"], assuming you fetched it on the create...

Comment: Well I create user stories in batches, I do not pull them, but I assume there is no way of obtaining that unless I fetch. Can you fetch after a create, I do not know how the code would look like, I have code when from when I fetched all the stories from Rally.